# Shift or displace, which is suitable for use with a mapping table

Tags: verbs

There is a mapping or correspondence table that defines a correspondence between people and tasks. For example, Smith, Johnson, and Jones are respectively assigned to go buy food, to cook breakfast, and to clean dishes.

When the correspondence is changed such that Smith, Johnson, and Jones are respectively assigned to cook breakfast, to clean dishes, and to go buy food, which of the following two sentences is more suitable for that meaning?

> The correspondence is shifted by one.
>   The correspondence is displaced by one.

Comment: Shifted is definitely better.  Also, such a table would typically be called a _roster_ or _schedule_, rather than _correspondence_.  Without some additional context added to the sentence, the listener would almost certainly interpret _correspondence_ in the sense of letters or email, not in the sense of a relationship between two sets of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the change in your list

> **Original list**
>   Smith - go buy food
>   Johnson - cook breakfast
>   Jones - clean dishes
>
> **New list**
>   Smith - cook breakfast
>   Johnson - clean dishes
>   Jones - go buy food

one would say the tasks are **shifted up by one** or the people are **shifted down by one**, the assumption is that the lists are a circular lists so the when one falls off the top/bottom it recycles to the bottom/top respectively.

If you were to say the were *displaced* it would imply something *new was added* to either list to *displace* the other list members.